# What is included in the Season Pass?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Does anyone have a list of the items which are included in the AC4 BF Season Pass?

I have bought the [Digital Deluxe Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/242050/), on PC from Steam, which already includes,

- Sacrifice Island
- Black Island
- Mystery Island
- Golden treasure chests for swords, outfits and ship customisations
- Aveline story DLC
- The Castaway's Prize

There is also some DLC already available,

- Death vessel pack
- Crusader & Florentine pack

[Wikipedia states that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_IV:_Black_Flag#Release),

> Ubisoft announced that a Season Pass will be available for purchase at
>   the launch of the game on PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, Xbox 360, Xbox
>   One and PC, and will include the **Freedom Cry single-player missions**,
>   **Kraken Ship pack** featuring elements to personalize the Jackdaw, as
>   well as **additional single-player and multiplayer elements**

Does this mean that only these items are available in the Season Pass? Will the Season Pass include the deluxe edition items for people who bought the standard edition of the game?

Comment: This is a bit speculative I think - nobody knows whether that is going to be all that is included in the season pass apart from the developers, and likely they won't even be completely sure this soon after release.

Comment: @kalina Which is why I was trying to put a spin on the question of a collated list of all currently available DLC. Worth me revising the question perhaps?

Comment: This questions should get more attention. As time has passed, more information should be available which may lead to a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Death Vessel and Crusader/Florintine pack are included as well, but dlc like the ones that unlock everything in multiplayer and the ones that unlock the whole map and stuff are not.